# Set variable with mathematical expression

Tags: graphics, scaling, calculations

I need to do something like the following,

```
\includegraphics[width=(\textwidth - 50mm)/2]{myfig.eps}
```

What keywords can I use to search for doing this operation? Everything I've searched for was about mathematical typing instead of setting variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth - 50mm)/2]{myfig.eps}
```

difficult to know that one has to search for \dimexpr

Answer (score 10):

### The LaTeX way: package `calc`

Package `calc` redefines `\setlength`, `\addtolength`, `\setcounter`, `\addtocounter` to support expressions. If another package uses these macros for setting length and counters with user provided values, then it inherits the power from package `calc`. It is enough to load the package, the other package does not even know about `calc`:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
...
\includegraphics[width=(\textwidth - 50mm)/2]{myfig.eps}
```

### The eTeX way: `\dimexpr`

If the eTeX extensions are enabled (usually the default for LaTeX based formats nowadays), \dimexpr can be used, where a TeX length is expected (see Herbert's answer):

```
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-50mm)/2]{myfig.eps}
```

### Comparison

- Dependencies: Package `calc` vs. eTeX
- eTeX's `\dimexpr`, `\numexpr`, … are expandable.
- `\dimexpr` also works, if internally `\setlength` is not used, e.g. `\vspace`.
- I expect `calc` to be slower, because of the internal macro work that needs to be done.
- `\dimexpr` calculates with higher precision.
- Package `calc` truncates: 5/2 = 2
  eTeX rounds: 5/2 = 3
- Package `calc` provides additional operators (`\widthof`, `\heightof`, `\totalheightof`, `\maxof`, `\minof`).

Comment: The TeX primitive `divide` truncates too.